# How do you overload Linq's Where clause to accept SqlBoolean?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, boolean, linq-to-objects

Linq's Where clause works with booleans. How do you get it to work with sqlBooleans. Here is sample code to illustrate the problem

```
// Trivia example to draw attention to the problem 
var nodeCollection = new List<SqlBoolean>();
nodeCollection.Add(SqlBoolean.Parse("0"));
nodeCollection.Add(SqlBoolean.Parse("1"));
nodeCollection.Add(SqlBoolean.Parse("1"));

var nodeA = SqlBoolean.Parse("1");
var trueOne = nodeCollection.Where(n => n == nodeA); // Error message, cannot convert SqlBoolean to bool
```

You get an error since the result of the predicate is SqlBoolean rather than bool. How do you extend the Where clause to make this work. Using casting, SqlBoolean's Value, IsTrue and IsFalse are not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the `SqlBoolean` to a `bool`. You can cast it [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc29k183(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var trueOne = nodeCollection.Where(n => (bool)(n == nodeA));
```

or compare the `Value` property:

```
var trueOne = nodeCollection.Where(n => n.Value == nodeA.Value);
```

The problem is that `SqlBoolean == SqlBoolean` returns `SqlBoolean` not `bool` since the [equality operator is overridden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes. However, I need it without cast.

Comment: If operator is overridden, then i'm afraid you can't do it without casting\using `nodaA.Value`...

Comment: Oh. Sergey, that is true for overriding, but how about overloading?

Comment: `SqlBoolean` is a `struct`, so you can't inherit it and overload method.... You can make some wrapper class around `SqlBoolean` with overloaded == operator, but not sure that it will be good way

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov. Thanks guys. You made good point and I did not think harder enough about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method to wrap the `Where`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereSqlBoolean<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,SqlBoolean> condition) {
    return source.Where(t => (bool)condition(t));
}
```

Still not the cleanest, but works:

```
var trueOne = nodeCollection.WhereSqlBoolean(n => n == nodeA);
```